# Transaction rollback hanging from past two months(MSSQL 2016)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log, rollback

I executed a query using **SQLCMD** on `2019-01-30`, and the query caused **ldf** file to bloat exponentially and it became 2TB in size, then my MSSQL started rollback of transaction at `2019-02-01`. I used `KILL SPID WITH STATUSONLY` to monitor the rollback process: progress of rollback was about **2% a day** for first two weeks, afterwards the rollback process got stuck at 22% from `2019-02-14`, and it's still there today.

I'd appreciate if I can get expert opinion on if there is any way to fix this issue - how to stop or speed up rollback?

Please find below code details about this issue:

---

### SQL

```
BEGIN TRAN
  DECLARE @m int
  SELECT @m = @@ERROR
  DECLARE @tbname_old varchar(50) = 'OTS_ARCHIVE'
  DECLARE @tbname_new varchar(50) = 'OTS_ARCHIVE2'
  DECLARE @column_old varchar(30) = 'GuID_ID'
  DECLARE @column_new varchar(30) = 'GuID_ID_old'
  DECLARE @sql varchar(50) = '[' + @tbname_new + '].[' + @column_old + ']'
  DECLARE @sqlid varchar(100) = 'CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) + CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(6)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)'
  DECLARE @date as datetime
  DECLARE @i int
  DECLARE @f int
  set @date = '2017-01-01'
  set @i = 0
  set @f = 27
  WHILE @i < @f
  BEGIN
  EXEC ('INSERT INTO ' + @tbname_new +
    ' select
    GuID_ID
    ,Box_ID
    ,Start_Time
    ,End_Time
    ,Duration_Time
    ,ots_count
    ,Group_ID
    ,' + @sqlid + ' from ' + @tbname_old
    )
  END
IF @m = 0
  COMMIT TRAN
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRAN
  SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
```

### Activity monitor

[image]

Comment: @SabinBio I ran the query and don't get any wait type shows `ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION`. Thanks.

Comment: What waits do you have for that session ? `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats` ; also a good helper is `sp_WhoIsActive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 60 days, the rollback process was finally completed. It seems the only way and the only solution you should do is **wait**, **wait**, and **keep waiting**.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what the transaction did?  What kind of disk subsystem do you have?  How much memory?  It's amazing that it took 60 days for rollback to complete!

Comment: How many [Virtual Log Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-log-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) does the database have?